# Issue with overlapping divs in CSS

Tags: css, image, layout, html, hyperlink

I'm working on a website right now that uses an image for navigation; you click on different components of the image, and they act as links to other pages. I looked at a tutorial that explained how to use 3 separate divs to get the effect I'm aiming for; a div that holds the main picture, an overlapping div that uses relative positioning, and a div that has the link image using absolute positioning. So far this method works pretty well for me and gives me the effect I want, but there's one small issue. In my browser I always get extra space leftover on the right side of the page. This issue is kinda hard for me to put into words, so I have an image of how the stacked divs appear in Dreamweaver and the issue as it appears in my browser.

[image]

[image]

You can look at the two garage doors in the first image and see the issue. The garage door on the far right appears properly in the web browser, perfectly overlaying the garage door on the left. However, as you can see in Dreamweaver, it sticks out past the background image and that extra blank space appears in the browser. Here's the code below.

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
            .body
            {
                height:100%;
                margin:0px auto;
                padding:0px;
            }
            .backgroundcontainer
            {
                width:100%;
                height:600px;
                background-image:url(backgroundstripe.png);
                background-repeat:repeat-x;
            }
            .background 
            {
                margin:0px auto;
                padding:0px;
                width:720px;
                height:600px;       
            }
            .textarea
            {
                margin:0px auto;
                padding:0px;
                background-color:#339900;   
            }
        </style>
```

And the body:

```
<body class="body">
        <center>
        <div class="backgroundcontainer">
            <div class="background" style="z-index:0">
                <!--House door link-->
                <div style="position:relative;top:449px;left:270px;z-index:1">
                    <div style="position:absolute">
                        <a href="[Link goes here]">
                            <img src="housedoor.png" height="151px" width="96px">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--Garage door link-->
                <div style="position:relative;top:451px;left:503px;z-index:1">
                    <div style="position:absolute">
                        <a href="[Link goes here]">
                            <img src="garagedoor.png" height="149px" width="130px">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--Window link-->
                <div style="position:relative;top:449px;left:375px;z-index:1">
                    <div style="position:absolute">
                        <a href="[Link goes here]">
                            <img src="window.png" height="97px" width="96px">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <img src="navigation.png" width="720px" height="600px">
            </div>
        </div>
        </center>
    </body>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are the actual dimensions of the images. A few things that concern me in looking at this are: 1) you should have no inline styling. Move the styling for your div elements to an external css. 2) you have height and width applied to the images inline. Why and is the sizing proportionate to the original image? Have you used Firebug or IE Dev Tools (F12) to examine the elements as the render in the ui to see what is being applied or inherited to the elements?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at your CSS (inline or not). You've also got to clean up your code...

- `<center>` is deprecated, but isn't causing your issue; however, you have it applied to a lot of 100% width elements...so there's nothing for it to center anyway. ([w3c reference](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/center))
- Measurements are passed to `<img>` as `px` by default -- adding "px" is probably causing the browser to ignore them. `height = "149" width = "130"` is what you want, if you're going to use that approach. ([w3c reference](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Images_in_HTML#The_img_element_and_its_attributes))
- `z-index` can only be used on elements with `position` applied to them (ie: `position:absolute/fixed/static/relative`) -- that first `z-index` is doing nothing at the moment, and from the code and your intent, is not needed. ([w3c reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-z-index))
- You're getting overlap because you've not assigned widths to any thing. Block elements are 100% wide (to their parent) by default. Your browser is fooling your eyes. Those elements aren't really acting the way you really want them to.([w3c reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3))

The best solution I can offer you:

- Place all 3 of your `position:absolute` divs into a single `position:relative` container (having more than one is giving you that stair step effect). Then give them each a height/width, and `z-index` (if it's still needed). You should start to see things come together pretty quickly.

HTH

Comment: Just for clarification adding px will not impact the rendering of the element it may be unnecessary but including it in the css or inline will not impact the rendering. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_height.asp

Comment: Awesome, fantastic help man, that cleaned up everything and took the amount of code down by a lot.